# how can I use PHPMailer to send emails with themosis/wordpress framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, phpmailer

I have a site that uses a framwork called([documentation here)](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/). A WordPress framework based on laravel, but I don't quite understand how the emails work.

**The direct question is: how can I use PHPMailer to send emails?**

At the moment, and for testing purposes, I want an email to be sent as soon as a page loads, so my controller method looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace Theme\Controllers;

use Themosis\Route\BaseController;
use Phpmailer\PHPMailer;

class OtherController extends BaseController {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "My username";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";
    $mail->setFrom('fromAddress@gmail.com', 'The name');
    $mail->addReplyTo('fromAddress@gmail.com', 'The name');
    $mail->addAddress('toAddress@gmail.com', 'Address');
    $mail->Subject = 'Contact us form sent';
    $mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';        

    return "Email sent";
}
```

I installed PHPMailer using composer, as per their documentation [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

When I hit the url, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 
'Phpmailer\PHPMailer' not found in 
/var/www/html/htdocs/content/themes/amarula/resources/controllers/OtherController.php on line 
141
```

Though the error message, I assume that the problem is in how I am attempting to access the mailer class, which is sitting in the vendor folder.

From the root of my application until my controller, the structure looks like the one below:

[image]

Ultimately, the PHPMailer class sits under the vendor folder, like in the structure below:

[image]

How do I access that class and send the email through my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this import:

```
use Phpmailer\PHPMailer;
```

That's not correct; it should be:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

The reason for this "triple name" is that it represents the PHPMailer class in the PHPMailer package belonging to the PHPMailer organisation.

One other thing that's kind of important - you won't receive any messages because you're never calling `$mail->send()`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - PHPmailer\PHPMailer instead of Phpmailer\PHPMailer
(https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php)

Second, you trying to find PHPMailer reletavely in namespace of your code.
`controllers/OtherController/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php`
And, of course, it doesn't exsits.

You should use `\PHPMailer\PHPMailer` to find class by absolute path

For more information, read about namespaces - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php